# Rails App behaves differently in console vs server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the following Class:

```
class DB
  cattr_accessor :get

  def self.connect(params)
    unless (params.has_key?(:user) && params.has_key?(:password))
      raise ArgumentError.new("Benutzername oder Passwort fehlen!")
    end
    self.get = Swift::DB::Mysql.new $dbconfig.merge(params)
    puts "Connection Successful from DB.connect"
  rescue Swift::ConnectionError
    puts "rescue Swift::ConnectionError in DB.connect"
    raise
  end

  # ...

end
```

and the following Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    DB.connect connection_params
    puts "connect: success!"
    # ...
    redirect_to root_url, info: "Hallo, #{session[:user]}!"
  rescue Swift::ConnectionError
    puts "rescue Swift::ConnectionError in SessionsController#create"
    flash.now[:danger] = "Benutzername oder Passwort falsch."
    render "new"
  end

  # ...

  private
  def connection_params
    params.permit(:user, :password)
  end
end
```

Ok, now i test everything in the `./bin/rails console`:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.5)
2.1.2 (main):0> params = {user: "foo", password: "bar"}
=> {:user=>"foo", :password=>"bar"}
2.1.2 (main):0> DB.connect(params)
rescue Swift::ConnectionError in DB.connect
Swift::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
from /path/to/app/models/concerns/db.rb:8:in `initialize'
```

Great, works out! Let's start `./bin/rails server` and call our Session controller!
But... no luck :( Server Log:

```
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-14 15:14:57 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...=", "user"=>"foo", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, commit
Connection Successful from DB.connect
connect: success!
...
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 2ms
```

Notice the `Connection Successful from DB.connect` output.

What am I missing? I've gone nearly mad testing this again and again, rewriting everything... Why does this behave differently in the console than it does on the server?

Answer (score 0):

For all non-GET requests, Rails expects an authenticity token. When you try from the console, it is not actually a web request. You are making a POST request with the correct authenticity token, hence it works in Web request.

Comment: Actually it's the other way around, it works correctly in the console but not via post. Also my problem is after the authenticy token is validated. In DB.connect i do not check for any authentication tokens whatsoever.

Comment: Then the only option is that the params are being sent as different values while doing POST. Print out the password and find out what is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found the problem thanks to @emaillenin 's comment:

When using Rails' integrated `params.permit(...)`, all keys are of type String.

So while on the console I was doing

```
Swift::DB::Mysql.new {:host=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>3306, :db=>"erp", :user=>"foo", :password=>"bar"}
```

on the server I was calling

```
Swift::DB::Mysql.new {:host=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>3306, :db=>"erp", "user"=>"foo", "password"=>"bar"}
```

which totally screwed up Swift. (Notice the different keys for `user` and `password`)